# ERROR: relation "students" already EXISTS

Tags: sql, postgresql, datagrip

When I am executing this query:

```
CREATE TABLE public.students (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT NEXTVAL('students_id_seq'::regclass),
  first_name CHARACTER VARYING(20) NOT NULL,
  last_name CHARACTER VARYING(20) NOT NULL,
  major CHARACTER VARYING(20) NOT NULL
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "Students_ID_uindex" ON students USING BTREE (id);

SELECT * FROM public.students;
```

I get the following error:

```
[2016-03-12 22:16:54] Run postgres.public.students [PostgreSQL - postgres@localhost]
[2016-03-12 22:16:54] Connecting TO PostgreSQL - postgres@localhost...
CREATE TABLE public.students (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT NEXTVAL('students_id_seq'::regclass),
  first_name CHARACTER VARYING(20) NOT NULL,
  last_name CHARACTER VARYING(20) NOT NULL,
  major CHARACTER VARYING(20) NOT NULL
)
[2016-03-12 22:16:54] [42P07] ERROR: relation "students" already EXISTS
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "Students_ID_uindex" ON students USING BTREE (id)
[2016-03-12 22:16:54] [42P07] ERROR: relation "Students_ID_uindex" already EXISTS
SELECT * FROM public.students
[2016-03-12 22:16:54] Executed IN 14ms ms

[2016-03-12 22:16:54] Summary: 3 OF 3 statements executed, 2 failed IN 68ms (338 symbols IN file)
```

I have made the table using DataGrip generate:
[image]

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

[image]

UPDATE: Just to clarify my question, when I first run the code with a new table name, I get now error but when I run it again I get the above error. How can this be fixed?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot create more tables with the same name - so statement `CREATE` should fail if there is a table with the same name already.

You can run the statement `DROP TABLE` before - but be aware! - it drops the table with all it's data, and **undo** is not possible. Second alternative is using the clause `IF NOT EXISTS` in `CREATE` statement:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS foo;
CREATE TABLE foo(a int);
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo(a int);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use an index name, just allow to PG to made it by itselves:

```
CREATE INDEX name ON public.students ("id");
```

Comment: How do I do if I now want to DROP that very index?

Comment: @Strazan sorry, missed the answer. Only one way to see it in your database application and use `DROP INDEX name`